# android: restart application instead of activity on language change

Tags: java, android, locale

I do have mutiple actvities and multiple fragments running in my application. Whenever i change the locale from the device language settings, only current activity gets restarted. Is there a way to restart the whole application on change in language under device setting ?

Comment: "_only current activity gets restarted_" - are you sure about that? Configuration changes should restart all the activities

Comment: it restarts all activities but it stays in current activity intead of starting again from first activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) to listen for the intent [`ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED), then upon receiving the intent you can do your logic of restarting the application. Like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //RESTART APPLICATION
    }
 };

//register broadcastreceiver
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext())
    .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED));

//remember to unregister in onDestroy with LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
```

To "restart" the application, you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourHomeActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
this.finishAffinity();
```

to start your home activity and clear all other activities.

Or something like this:

```
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

to actually stop the application and restart 100ms (set it to whatever you want) later.